# Python: Matplotlib transparent colormap, how to get rid of lines between boxes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a custom colormap going from red to transparent. When I plot a pcolormesh some darker color lines show between some boxes. What's causing the edge color and how can I get ride of it? (It's not the edgecolor option in pcolormesh)

```
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random([10,10])

colors = [(1,0,0,i) for i in np.linspace(0,1,15)]
cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', colors, N=3)

plt.pcolormesh(a,cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that the semi-transparent patches overlap and give red lines.

Comment: In addition to the workaround mentioned in the linked duplicate, consider using `imshow` with `interpolation='nearest'` instead.

Comment: The workaround in the previous post didn't work for me (lines too thick and dark to cover). Using imshow is a good alternative. For my purposes contourf also makes a good looking plot, too.